# How to build an inverted index for multi-dimensional attributes?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, indexing, inverted-index

I have data in the form of userID-> (col1,col2,col3), where each user has a set of (col1,col2,col3) values)

I organize `(col1,col2,col3)` into a KD-Tree and perform nearest neighbour queries on it. After getting the nearest neighbours, I want to do reverse lookup where which `(col1,col2,col3)` correspond to which user. Is this something that can be build in a KDTree. Are there any different approaches to index data of such kind.

Comment: why not just another hashtable?

Comment: @Larry Too much memory?

Comment: In your kd-tree, why not take (col1,col2,col3) as the "key" and userID as the value? In C/C++, you can also pack (userID,col1,col2,col3) in one struct. This should be a pretty standard thing.